# Efeito de parallax quando passa o mouse em cima

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Gostaria de saber como faço esse efeito que tem [nesse site](http://www.destinythegame.com/pt/expansions/expansion-one) ou [nesse outro](http://www.digitalhands.net/).

Quando eu passo o mouse em cima da imagem ela se mexe.

Um detalhe importante é que não importe onde eu passe o mouse, a imagem sempre tem que mexer no segundo *link* isso fica bem nítido.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#Parallax').mousemove(
    function(e) {
      /* Work out mouse position */
      var offset = $(this).offset();
      var xPos = e.pageX - offset.left;
      var yPos = e.pageY - offset.top;

      /* Get percentage positions */
      var mouseXPercent = Math.round(xPos / $(this).width() * 100);
      var mouseYPercent = Math.round(yPos / $(this).height() * 100);

      /* Position Each Layer */
      $(this).children('img').each(
        function() {
          var diffX = $('#Parallax').width() - $(this).width();
          var diffY = $('#Parallax').height() - $(this).height();

          var myX = diffX * (mouseXPercent / 100); //) / 100) / 2;


          var myY = diffY * (mouseYPercent / 100);


          var cssObj = {
              'left': myX + 'px',
              'top': myY + 'px'
            }
            //$(this).css(cssObj);
          $(this).animate({
            left: myX,
            top: myY
          }, {
            duration: 50,
            queue: false,
            easing: 'linear'
          });

        }
      );

    }
  );
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #3D7991;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
  line-height: normal;
}
.Clear {
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}
a {
  color: #3D7991;
}
.Return {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
#Dev {
  position: absolute;
}
#OuterBox {
  background-color: #FAFAF2;
  margin: 25px auto auto auto;
  padding: 25px;
  position: relative;
  width: 750px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px #2A5364;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px #2A5364;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#Parallax {
  background-color: #880088;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 750px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#Parallax img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Parallax">
  <img src="http://publicdomainvectors.org/photos/cloud_jon_phillips_01.png" />
  <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-pOjvZCG09C4/Uyo8SszT0iI/AAAAAAAAPBY/7HtQrWmHyYg/s1600/molde-nuvem-desenho.png" />
  <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-g11nccDlhlY/U_u4DBMTv9I/AAAAAAAARX8/tjurGjgli4I/s1600/Cute%2B-%2Bnuvem%2B-%2BCria%C3%A7%C3%A3o%2BBlog%2BPNG-Free.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uMk7m/2/ e isso aqui so que e mais trabalhado o meu

Comment: eu tenho 5 imagens e quero movelas nesse exemplo so tem 2  e queria que o efeito ficasse parecido com a do link porem voce nao consegue entrar mais tenta digitar no google destiny site oficial

Comment: Veja alguns desses resultados utilizando Bootstrap 3: http://www.bootply.com/tagged/parallax. Mas pelo que você disse, você quer um efeito ao passar o mouse nas imagens e não um `parallax`, correto?

Comment: acho que sim chegou a ver o outro link ai que acabei de mandar e tambem editei a pergunta e adicionei mais um link tbm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em geral esse efeito é feito com o parallax do jQuery.

Aqui um artigo completo sobre [Parallax simples com JQuery e CSS](http://tableless.com.br/parallax-simples-com-jquery-e-css/)

Aqui uns sites com exemplos:

[50+ Best JQuery Parallax](http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-parallax-plugin/)

[Parallax.js](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/)

Creio que com essas fontes tu deves conseguir fazer o que deseja!

Abraços! (:
Observação: [uma print do site que tu mesmo mandou](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FCZL.jpg).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Aqui um site com um exemplo do JS BEM SIMPLES para a implementação.](http://www.shinyface.com/2010/09/04/simple-parallax-with-jquery/)

Comment: Comentários [movidos para o bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23467/discussion-on-answer-by-andrey-hartung-efeito-de-parallax-quando-passa-o-mouse-e).

Answer (score -2):

Desloque a imagem com baixo fator, inércia e atrito com deslocamento contrário ao mouse. 
O mouse será tratado como um vetor aceleração e a imagem terá grande massa.

Comment: amigo poderia ser mais especifico chegou a dar um olhadinha nos links

Comment: A tá vocês estão acostumados as fórmulas e os códigos fontes (tudo pronto). Nada contra, mas estou sem tempo agora.